# Can this old-style ajax call be easily done with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, migration

I'm working with some pretty old code and the following is being used to monitor session status.  If the user is inactive for X minutes (determined by check_session.php), they are logged out.

The server side stuff works fine.   Actually, the existing javascript appears to work OK as well, but looks like it needs cleaning up.

Here's the existing javascript:

```
function checkSessionStatus() 
{ 
    session_http.open('GET', '/check_session.php', true); 
    session_http.onreadystatechange = handleSessionHttpResponse; 
    session_http.send(null); 
}

function handleSessionHttpResponse() 
{ 
    if (session_http.readyState == 4) 
    { 
        results = session_http.responseText; 
        if (results == 'inactive') 
        {
            window.location='/logout.php';
            document.getElementById('session_divbox').innerHTML = results; 
        }
    }
}

function get_session_HTTPObject() 
{
    var xml_session_http; 
    if (!xml_session_http && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') 
    { 
        try 
        { 
            xml_session_http = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        } 

        catch (e) 
        { 
            xml_session_http = false; 
        } 
    } 
    return xml_session_http; 
} 
var session_http = get_session_HTTPObject(); 

function init_page_header() 
{
    window.setInterval( 'checkSessionStatus();',  30000);
}
```

This seems incredibly long for what it is doing.

I am still learning jquery and am able to do some basic ajax calls like this one, which places a returned value in a div:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('#users_online').load('/show_users_online.php');
    var refreshId = setInterval(function() 
    {
        $('#users_online').load('/show_users_online.php');
    }, 2000);
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```

The issue with the first bit of code is that it returns a value of 'inactive', which is then acted on by the client (window redirect).

Is it possible to do this in Jquery without winding up with dozens of lines of code?   I may already know how to do this and am not seeing the forest for the trees -- some guidance here is appreciated.

Comment: If you are already using jQuery for other things, fine. If you are planning on using jQuery to replace your already functioning vanilla ajax (and understand XHR).... why... sure YOU write less code (once, seems you already have a copy paste script to use)... but the overhead adds up. It's not a lot, but why add more overhead when it is not needed?

Comment: I recently went through all of the code and replaced prototype with jquery - so yeah it's already in play.  This is one I had planned to convert, and am just getting to it.

Comment: As a side note: you probably don't need to load ALL of the data each time. Whenever a new user logs in or out update a server session variable for the timestamp this happened on. Ensure this is sent to the client with the initial HTML data. Now on the server you can check to see ***if*** the HTML is even needed to be sent. Just saved yourself a little bandwidth, and your clients as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if its very *vampiric question style*, should look like

```
$.get('/check_session.php', function( data ) {
    if( data === 'inactive' ) { 
        window.location='/logout.php';
        document.getElementById('session_divbox').innerHTML = data;
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm not following your "vampiric question style" reference.   Le Goog returns:  No results found for "vampiric question style".

Comment: Meh, not using `html()` or jQuery's selectors? @jAndy, you disappoint me.

Comment: Oh, good grief.  How can I word so I don't have someone rewrite my code?  That honestly isn't what I'm after.  I'm not sure what exactly I need to ask -- I think I addressed it by saying I wasn't sure how to get a value back from an ajax call, and use it for an action (like the window redirect).

Comment: @FlorianMargaine: question was just about ajax :-)

Comment: @acoder read "10 simple steps to not being a Help Vampire." in the link provided by jAndy & rlemon.

Comment: It sounds like my choices are to either not ask questions, or to ask questions only after I have "learned this shit" (eliminating the need to ask the question in the first place), thus avoiding having someone else "write my code".

Comment: @acoder: nobody is discouraging you from asking questions. The *vampiric* term is more used in a way that, if questions are asked in an overly "broad" way, like "How to rule the world", or "How to build an OS" (hyperbolismed).

Comment: I get the gist of your point, but I'm having trouble sympathizing with your perspective -- I did not ask anyone to make me a sammich.  I showed you my baloney sandwich, showed a tastier looking panino, and asked how to help make the better kind.  I indicated that I am not yet experienced in making paninos, but that I am learning.  I asked for `some guidance` not a complete code rewrite.  I appreciate your assistance, but I don't agree that my question was out of line.  If you believe it was, feel free to mark it for deletion.

Comment: To be fair to myself, I never actually read anything to do with this question (aside from reading the code and skimming the text). I was asked to make the article linkable and did then dropped the link in here. Now you kids play nice!